# Wrap String with For Loop or If Statement

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, for-loop

Let's say that we have a string declared...

```
string paragraphy = "This is a really really long string containing a paragraph long content. I want to wrap this text by using a for loop to do so.";
```

With this string variable I want to wrap the text if it is more than 60 width and if there is a space after those the 60 width.

Can someone please provide me with the code or any help in creating something like this.

Comment: By "wrap" you mean insert `\n` into the appropriate places?

Comment: yes. so wrap after width 60 and space.

Comment: This sounds like a typical homework question, if it is you should tag it as such.

Comment: You'll need to show us what you've tried, and what specifically you are stuck on.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

A basic idea to solving this is to keep track of the last space in a segment of the string before the 60th character in that segment.

Since this is homework, I'll let you come up with the code, however here's some rough pseudo-code of the above suggestion:

```
- current_position = start of the string
- WHILE current_position NOT past the end of the string
   - LOOP 1...60 from the current_position (also don't go past the end of the string)
      - IF the character at current_position is a space, set the space_position to this position
   - Replace the character (the space) at the space_position with a newline
   - Set the current_position to the next character after the space_position

- If you're printing the string rather than inserting newline characters into it, you would print any remaining part of the string here.
```

You might also want to consider the case where you don't have any spaces in a block of 60 characters.

Comment: thank you! i will try this on my own & post the code i come up with.